# Emacs auto-save on switch buffer

Tags: emacs, autosave

Call me lame, but I'm tired of my subconscious `C-x C-s` nervous twitch.  I am switching buffers often enough and I think I would like to save a certain buffer as soon as I switch to another.  I have not had the time yet to learn Emacs-Lisp basics.

Any hints on how to do this, or better solutions?

(On a related note, I found an [autosave workaround](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave) that can save the current buffer as soon as you are idle for a given amount of time.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To expand on [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8590/seth)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413837/emacs-auto-save-on-switch-buffer/1413883#1413883), I'd do this:

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (before save-buffer-now activate)
  (when buffer-file-name (save-buffer)))
(defadvice other-window (before other-window-now activate)
  (when buffer-file-name (save-buffer)))
(defadvice other-frame (before other-frame-now activate)
  (when buffer-file-name (save-buffer)))
```

The check for `buffer-file-name` avoids saving buffers w/out files.  You need to figure out all the entry points you use for switching buffers that you care about (I'd also advise `other-window`).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :) 6 years later and still a great answer

Answer (score 6):

I'm kind of new to emacs lisp myself but this works in my testing:

```
(defadvice switch-to-buffer (before save-buffer-now)
  (save-buffer))

(ad-activate 'switch-to-buffer)
```

It's kind of annoying though because it's called after EVERY buffer (like *scratch*).  So, consider this answer a hint.

When you want to disable it, you'll need to call:

```
(ad-disable-advice 'switch-to-buffer 'before 'save-buffer-now)
(ad-activate 'switch-to-buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas.

First, if you find yourself invoking a command like save with a sufficiently high frequency, you might consider a shorter key binding for the command. For example, I also found myself having the same "twitch," so now I use `f2` instead of `C-x C-s` for saving edits.

The function that I bind to `f2` saves every unsaved buffer unconditionally. You might find it useful:

```
(defun force-save-all ()
    "Unconditionally saves all unsaved buffers."
    (interactive)
    (save-some-buffers t))

(global-set-key [f2] 'force-save-all)
```

Now, on to the main issue. You could try something like this (notice that `force-save-all` is called):

```
(defun my-switch-to-buffer (buffer)
    (interactive (list (read-buffer "Switch to buffer: " (cadr buffer-name-history) nil)))
    (force-save-all)
    (switch-to-buffer buffer))

(global-set-key "\C-xb" 'my-switch-to-buffer)
```

Of course, you could also bind the switch buffer functionality to another key, like a function key, so that it's a one press operation.

I thought that [@seth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8590/seth) had a great idea about using advice, but I noticed that the ELisp manual suggests that [advice not be used for key bindings](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html.gz#Advising-Functions). I'm not quite sure why this is the case, but that's what the manual suggests FYI.

Comment: Interesting.  Didn't see that part about keybindings when I was reading the manual.  Thanks.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is when you e.g. start using `ido-switch-buffer`, you have to track down the changes in your function, too.

Comment: That's true, I suppose you could rebind the switch-to-buffer symbol to this new function (saving the original in another symbol, e.g. orig-save-to-buffer)